# How to show Firebase data in recyclerview without duplicates

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I add a post, the list repeats again, I would like add just one post .

No problem when writing data on Firebase but there is a problem when reading from Firebase, all posts repeats ..

```
   final NotesAdapter notesAdapter=new NotesAdapter(list,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference("Posts");

    Query query =  databaseReference.orderByKey();

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { 
  
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Listdata listdata=dataSnapshot1.getValue(Listdata.class); 
                list.add(listdata); 

                       }
            notesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to clear the list before you get info from database, then add elements and do adapter.notifySetDataChange().

Comment: thnks .  I have added   list.clear();   And it succeeded with me

Comment: how i can move the view on the top app when i added new post ?

Comment: if you talking about an item, you can just simply add item at 0 index